# automake "permissions denied"

Tags: compiling

i want to compile changes i made to a project created with automake.

I changed my Makefile.am files accordingly and ran

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

make finally gives me the error:

```
...
make[2]: Betrete Verzeichnis '/home/dino/workspace/ba/sharp-1.0/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -      I../include -I../include/sharp -ansi --pedantic-error -Wall   -g -O2 -MT Global.lo -MD -   MP -MF .deps/Global.Tpo -c -o Global.lo `test -f './Global.cpp' || echo './'`./Global.cpp
../libtool: line 2090: ./Global.cpp: Permission denied
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../include -I../include/sharp -ansi     --pedantic-error -Wall -g -O2 -MT Global.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/Global.Tpo -c ""  -fPIC -  DPIC -o .libs/Global.o
g++: error: : No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

The command above doesn't work on any source file. So i imagined it could only be my automake that broke the project.

Comment: Finally I figured it out, i had my automake and the libtool version of the project were incompatible.

Building the configuration with my local automake and replacing the libtool of the project with my local libtool solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I come across an issue like this, its due to not using the `sudo` prefix.

```
sudo ./autogen.sh
sudo ./configure.sh
sudo make
```

What the problem is you as a user don't have permission to use whatever file is required, and the make process is cancelled.  Executing as `sudo` solves the issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, but executing the commands as sudo doesn't solve the issue, i already checked all permissions and ran the commands as superuser too, but it didn't help.